# Dealing with Images in adaptive and responsive layouts

Tags: css, media-queries, css-sprites, responsive-design

What is the best way to handle image(or sprites) while dealing with responsive and adaptive layouts ? The way I do it now is using media queries which has conditional image selection based on the view port dimension. Is there a better method and why ?.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `images` also be `responsive` (resizing) then `sprite` is not a good idea. It's better to use as a single image But if the images is not `responsive` (resizing) then you can use as an sprites .

Never give `sprites` in the `background` of any responsive element. It's `height` & `width` should be fixed .

Comment: I agree to what you said and to what I assume, it is the preffered practice being followed these days. What I ment here was , is there a way to resize the original sprite dynamically in proportion to the screen being served and the background co-ordinates adjusted to meet this dimension. By this I intend to make the image re-usable for multiple dimension. Also I understand that this method might involve  a little compromise with the image quality and hence not targeted for high end solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method: **[Stretchy Sprites](http://tobyj.net/responsive-sprites)** (instructions & demo) - Pure HTML/CSS with no reliance on `background-size`

Comment: This is a gem of a solution for those wanting to use CSS sprites in adaptive design. Im still trying to get my gray matter to understand the code & the whys but if it works as promisingly as in your examples, I'd be happy to give you a big manly hug!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, responsive design is half making dynamic / resizable content (flex box, vector/scalable images, etc.) and half using media queries - so yes part of it can be using conditional image selection with media queries.

As for scalable images, are you talking more about icons / small images or large / user uploaded images that need to retain high quality?

For icons / small images (such as you would put in a .png image sprite), I'd try vector images, which are infinitely scalable:

- icon fonts (only works for uni-color icons but can be styled with CSS so they're pretty easy to work with):

http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/
http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#base-icons

Software needed: vector image editor (Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape) and font editor (FontCreator, FontForge).

- SVGs - a little trickier to work with but can handle more complex graphics.

Software needed: vector image editor (I recommend Adobe Illustrator)
Here's an example of a completely resizable page of svg's with no media queries:
http://emacsformacosx.com/

The advantage to vector graphics is that they'll work on any screen size and they typically load faster (smaller filesize) so if you're serious about "going responsive" I'd try to do everything in vectors.

That's just the "tip of the iceberg" so to say - happy to share more if you have specific questions; it took me awhile to figure out how to get the software setup and implement the above cross browser (for example Android below 4.0 doesn't support SVG so I had to rely on .png sprites still and I wrote a javascript file that allowed for resizable sprites - similar to the "stretchy sprites" post) - that's another advantage of icon fonts if you can get away with single color icons.

Comment: SVG is great, however the share of non supporting browsers is significant. Any polyfill that you would like to suggest ?

Comment: Where are you basing your comment that "the share of non supporting browsers is significant"? Support (at least for basic SVGs) is strong: http://caniuse.com/#search=svg The only browser that I worry about that doesn't support it is Android 2.3 and below. And for that I use canvg polyfill: http://code.google.com/p/canvg/

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Images by Matt Wilcox is probably what you're after.

http://adaptive-images.com/

It takes the users screen size into account using Javascript and serves up cached resized versions of the images depending on the size available.

It basically looks for smaller cached images and serves them up if they're found and makes them if they're not.

Comment: This is still being implemented using @media queries. I like the logic of media queries that provides conditional scenarios for varying screen dimensions. But the facts that particular images have to created for the targeted screen is a redundant procedure and also each call for these images is an extra over head. What I mean by this is, I am trying to find out a way (if exists) where in an images is created in such a way that it can be re sized without having distortion and that serves up multiple screen sizes.

Comment: "However this isn't really a long-term solution, not least because of the cookie race condition and CDN/proxy-cache incompatibility. What we really need are a number of standardised ways to handle this in the future". This para exits on the site (http://adaptive-images.com/details.htm). This project is a very interesting approach and initiative , however the limitations (only php, no CDN and cookie dependent) are huge enough to be ignored.

Comment: So far it's the best approach I've found but if you're serving up different size images on the screen at once it falls down. I'm looking in to building my own version that takes this into account but it is the best I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I recently reviewed quite a bit of material on this subject. There's quite a few methodologies available none of which are absolute. I used background images (with background-size: contain or background-size: cover) for all images that were static (iconography, etc). However, dynamically generated images are difficult to manage in an elegant (non-script) paradigm. Therefore, after reviewing many scripts, I just wrote my own. I hope this helps:

```
/**
 * Retina image update script. Invoke with Retina.render().
 * Retina.render() may be passed a selector for img selection.
 * The default filter looks for img's with data-scale="retina".
 * @param {string|function} expr    A CSS selector expression or jQuery filter function.
 * @return {boolean|collection}     Returns false or (for Retina displays) the images updated.
 * @author Joe Johnson
 */
(function(ns,$){
    ns.Retina = {
        render: (function(isRetina){
            return isRetina ? function(expr){
                var r1 = /retina/i, r2 = /\d{3}/,
                    filter = expr ? expr : function(){
                        return r1.test($(this).data("scale"));
                    };
                return $("img").filter(filter).each(function(){
                    this.src = this.src.replace(r2,function(m){
                        return (parseInt(m,10)>=640 ? m : 2*m);
                    });
                });
            } : function(){ return false; };
        })(ns.devicePixelRatio && (ns.devicePixelRatio > 1))
    };
})(window,jQuery);
```

It should be noted that you still need to rely on some filename convention (in this case, r2 -- regular expression -- is searching for a directory in the image src attribute with a value based on the dimension [img/blah/320/image.jpg gets updated to img/blah/640/image.jpg]. Images which already have a src with a directory containing a number greater than 640 will be skipped as I'm assuming they're already large enough for Retina displays (the site I used this on has images in directories /img/dir/320/, /img/dir/640, and /img/dir/960).